# Extract response code and part of one specific header from curl on OSX

Tags: shell, curl, sh

I am writing shell scripts in macOS 11.1 Big Sur to test several endpoints thru cUrl request. To improve my scripts, I would love to do the following:

- send the curl request
- store the response code to a variable in an array
- store part of the response payload to another variable

*I can not share the exact endpoint since that would be a security breach for others to test their solutions, unfortunately.*
In example, using a modified request from one of my scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
EMAIL_USERNAME=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
curl -iX POST 'http://test.someclientcloud.com/api/online/customer/register' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'X-Origin-Source: WWW' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8' --data-binary $'{ "emailAddress": "'$EMAIL_USERNAME'@xxxxxx.com", "firstName": "Terminate", "lastName": "ME", "opt": true, "password": "Password7654!", "phoneNumber": "555229'$TODAY'", "regCity": "Anytown", "regCountryCode": "1", "regState": "TX", "regZip": "86753", "username": "'$EMAIL_USERNAME'@xxxxx.com" }'
```

The curl response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2021 18:40:38 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: /api/customer/354190751
Expires: 0
requestDuration: 67
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Origin-Source: WWW
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
proxyUser: WWW
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Application-Context: application:production
```

The two things I would like from that response are **201** for the response code, from the first line of the response.

And **354190751** from the end of line 7 of the response above.

I can use these responses to form a report at the end of the script of each response per request. And I can use the newly created customer number in further tests within the script to modify the account further or delete the account for clean up at the end of the test.

I suspect this can be done with clever regex?  My regex level is only moderately dangerous.

To be clear, I will mention, **this is Apple Shell Scripting** in macOS 11.1 Big Sur. Variants of shell scripting are many.
Hopefully the question was clear, thank you for your help.

Added that this is macOS 11.1 Big Sur

Comment: "Apple shell scripting" doesn't tell us much; there are many different shells even shipped on MacOS. Which _specific_ shell, and which version of that shell, would be more helpful. Even something like "/bin/sh on Catalina" would be more to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, while `curl` lets you ask it to directly write the status code, that doesn't extend to individual headers -- so you need to do the pattern matching yourself. One way to do that is as follows (note the use of [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) syntax to avoid the issues discussed in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), which makes this incompatible with `/bin/sh`; that said, because your code uses [ANSI C-like string syntax](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings), aka `$''`, it isn't compliant with the `sh` standard regardless):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# put your actual curl code here; using a stub here so others can test
getCurlOutput() {
cat <<'EOF'
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: /api/customer/354190751
Expires: 0
EOF
}

code=
customer=
{
  read _ code _
  prefix="Location: /api/customer/"
  while IFS= read -r line; do line=${line%$'\r'}
    case $line in
      "$prefix"*) customer=${line#$prefix};;
    esac
  done
} < <(getCurlOutput)

echo "Retrieved exit status $code"
if [ -n "$customer" ]; then
  echo "Customer id retrieved is $customer"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you.  My own code is ummm... not "kosher", maybe, but it has been working well for me. I had to play (`,',") roulette to find a combo that worked in my script.
I will be spending some time testing your answer and let you know how well it works for me.